# How to lock auto exposure in android using camera2 api

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am using `android-Camera2Basic` google sample. I am trying to add regional focus and regional exposure using `CONTROL_AF_REGIONS` and `CONTROL_AE_REGIONS`. I have some problem regarding lock auto exposure algorithm.

Here is what I have done so far:

1- cancel previous auto exposure and auto focus triggers:

```
mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, false);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_CANCEL);
mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

2- add desired regions for auto focus and auto exposure:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_REGIONS, meteringRectangleArr);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_REGIONS, meteringRectangleArr);
```

3- set focus triggers:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AF_TRIGGER_START);
mState = STATE_WAITING_LOCK;
mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

4- In the `mCaptureCallback` I have the following code which set auto exposure trigger when camera locked on focus:

```
try {                                                                                                                                        
    switch(mState) {                                                                                                                         
        case STATE_PREVIEW: {                                                                                                                
            break;                                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                    
        case STATE_WAITING_LOCK: {                                                                                                           
            Integer afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE);                                                                    
            if (CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState ||                                                                  
                CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED == afState) {
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_PRECAPTURE_TRIGGER_START);
                mState = STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE;
                mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            }                                                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                                                    
        case STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE: {
            Integer aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE);
            if (CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED == aeState || CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED == aeState) { //2, 4  
                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);
                mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        } else if(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_LOCKED == aeState) {                                                                   
                mState = STATE_PREVIEW;
                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);                                  
            }                                                                                                                                
        }                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                        
} catch (CameraAccessException e) {                                                                                                          
    e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                     
}
```

With these codes, the auto focus and auto exposure will work fine on `Samsung Note8`. But the problem is the same code does not work on `Samsung J5`. The problem is when the camera tries to focus(in J5), it's stock in an infinive loop between `CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED` and `CONTROL_AF_STATE_ACTIVE_SCAN` and the preview will freeze. If I change the `mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);` with `mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);`, the J5 will work fine on auto focus region(J5 does not support auto exposure region. So I commented out the auto exposure parts for J5!). But when I apply this modification on Note8, the exposure will apply but will not lock and after a few frames, it back to the previous exposure.

So, what is wrong? should I use `mPreviewRequestBuilder.build()` or `mPreviewRequest` in `mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest` method? why J5 stock if I use `mPreviewRequestBuilder.build()`?